# Deleting dynamic elements in a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dynamic

I have a program that has a vector. The vector takes pointers to an object which I dynamically create in my program. I then wish to delete these dynamic objects from the vector. For example:

```
int main()
{
    vector<Account*> allAccounts;
    auto timeDone = chrono::system_clock::now();
    time_t transactionTime = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(timeDone);
    Account* a1 = new Savings(0, "Savings");
    Account* a2 = new Current(0, "Current");
    allAccounts.push_back(a1);
    allAccounts.push_back(a2);
    Transaction* initialTransaction = new Transaction("Initial Deposit", transactionTime, balanceAnswer);
    allAccounts[0]->addTransaction(initialTransaction);
    allAccounts[1]->addTransaction(initialTransaction);
    for (int i = 0; i < allAccounts.size(); i++) 
    {
        delete allAccounts[i]; //deletes all dynamically created accounts
    }
}
```

I believed this was fine to do, however I'm starting to wonder if this does correctly delete the pointers in the vector. However I used a `cout << allAccounts.size()` after the delete and it still gives the size as `2` as if the account pointers were still in the vector.

Is this meant to happen?

Another note is that the `Account` object also has a vector of dynamic pointers that get passed from main in a function (`allAccounts[i]->addObject(object)`) and then these objects get deleted in a destructor in the same way. Is this also a valid thing to do?
Just so I get my worries out the way, this is what I do in account:

```
float balance;
string accountType 
private vector <Transaction*> history;
Account::Account(float b, string a) 
{
    balance = b;
    accountType = a;
}
void Account::addTransaction(Transaction* t)
{
    history.push_back(t); 
}
Account::~Account() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < history.size(); i++) 
    {
        delete history[i];
    }
    history.clear();
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Account>>` might be safer.

Comment: Add `allAccounts.clear();` after the loop. Related: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear)

Comment: ***Is this meant to happen?*** Yes. Your delete frees the object that the pointer points to. Your vector contains a vector of pointers. It does not care if the pointer points to a valid memory. `delete allAccounts[i];` does not remove the pointer from the vector. It frees the object that `allAccounts[i];` points to

Comment: Oh yes I remember now, I forget that the pointer itself isn't deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is fine (assuming `Account` has a `virtual` destructor) and there is no memory leak. The size of the `vector` is not affected by deleting the pointers you store in it.

The destructor needs to be `virtual` to not cause your program to have *undefined behavior*.

I would recommend storing a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<Account>` in the `vector` instead though. That would make the destruction of the stored objects automatic when the `vector`.is destroyed.

Comment: Account doesn't in fairness have a virtual destructor, it does have a destructor as it itself has another vector of dynamic objects as well. The derived objects don't have destructors since the vector is only used and stored in the base class. Does it still need to be virtual anyway?

Comment: Just in case you need to see it I've made an ammedment to my question to include the destructor

Comment: @RadioCode345 I added a comment about that to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll be sure to make the destructor virtual now.